# Accidently deleted JRE from my Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, project, java

I have opened a new Java project, wrote a lot of code, added a few external jars.
I wanted to delete one external jar, accidently deleted the JRE library.

Can't figure out how to re-add the JRE to the project.

Answer (score 6):

Oh ofcourse, I missed the "Add library" Button.

Right click project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries Tab (JRE is missing!)->Add Library->Choose a library.

How the hell did I miss that.

Answer (score 0):

**Right click project**->**Properties**->**Build Path**->**Add Libraries**->**JRE System Library**->**Finish**
I hope that was helpful