# Missing reference to the JRE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse project is missing the reference to the JRE. I wanted to upgrade from JRE 1.6 to JRE 1.8 and without first looking into the `Windows > Preferences`, I did not see any easy way to do it. I proceeded to delete the reference to 1.6. After doing that I found that I can add JRE 1.8 in `Windows > Preferences` so I added it and applied it. However, the package explorer pane still has no reference for the JRE. How can I fix this?

*Edit: This is a duplicate. Please see the link posted by K.Chandrakala N.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602274/accidently-deleted-jre-from-my-eclipse-project check this link it may be helpful to you

Comment: Did you change your classpath with 1.8

Comment: My understanding is that classpath is just a command line option.

Comment: K. Chandrakala N, thanks the info at the link helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the particular JRE (in your case JRE 1.8) as the default one. If not select the JRE as the default one from `Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE` by using the check box near it (as shown in the image). And Check whether the problem prevails...[Preferences Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ftp2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`.

Add/Edit your JREs here. Below is the screenshot to help you out.

[image]